# XSLT Generating incremental values

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml:

```
<Details>
    <Head>
        <pageid>123</pageid> <!-- Needs to be sequential starting with 0000000001 -->
    </Head>
    <Start>
        <pageid>124</pageid>
        <value>Details of Minerals</value>
    </Start>
    <Item>
        <pageid>12</pageid>
        <name>Coal</name>
    </Item>
    <Quantity>
        <pageid>45</pageid>
        <value>3</value>
        <comments>NONE MENTIONED</comments>
    </Quantity>
    <Item>
        <pageid>459</pageid>
        <name>MICA</name>
    </Item>
    <Quantity>
        <pageid>65</pageid>
        <value>2</value>
        <comments>NONE MENTIONED</comments>
    </Quantity>
    <END>
        <pageid>78</pageid>
    </END>
</Details>
```

I want to the value `pageid` to be incremental with 10 digits.

**Sample o/p**

```
    <Details>
    <Head>
        <pageid>0000000001</pageid>
    </Head>
    <Start>
        <pageid>0000000002</pageid>
        <value>Details of Minerals</value>
    </Start>
    <Item>
        <pageid>0000000003</pageid>
        <name>Coal</name>
    </Item>
    <Quantity>
        <pageid>0000000004</pageid>
        <value>3</value>
        <comments>NONE MENTIONED</comments>
    </Quantity>
    <Item>
        <pageid>0000000005</pageid>
        <name>MICA</name>
    </Item>
    <Quantity>
        <pageid>0000000006</pageid>
        <value>2</value>
        <comments>NONE MENTIONED</comments>
    </Quantity>
    <END>
        <pageid>0000000007</pageid>
    </END>
</Details>
```

I tried using the following construct:

`<xsl:variable name="counter" select="0000000000" saxon:assignable="yes"/>`

```
<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='pageid']">
<saxon:assign name="counter" select="$counter+0000000001"/>
<imp1:Line_id>
<xsl:value-of select="$counter"></xsl:value-of>
</imp1:Line_id>
```

But this wasnt helpful. Can u suggest a easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use a variable counter, you could just make use of the `xsl:number` element here:

```
<xsl:template match="//*[local-name()='pageid']">
    <imp1:Line_id>
        <xsl:number level="any" format="0000000000" />
    </imp1:Line_id>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. It worked for me. Dunno why, I am using jdeveloper 11g and `format ="0000000001"` seems to work, whereas `format="0000000000"` does not.